# What is a word for someone who intentionally ignores other people a lot?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

I always used to think the word was *ignorant* but it has turned out that I am wrong.

Comment: Right now I'm ignoring six billion people. Do you have some particular scenario in mind where someone is seeking attention and not getting it? I suggest `not-a-stalker`.

Comment: Can you avoid the smart- ass comments in future please?

Comment: While @user814064 could indeed have been more polite, they raise a valid point. Could you give us an example sentence or describe the situation a bit more? See our FAQ on [how to ask questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Maybe someone is getting ignored because they're acting unavailable? That's why I used the word stalker. Attention is a two-way street. It can be unwanted or wanted. If someone is not giving attention ask them why. When you get the answer, you'll have a label that you can enjoy using.

Comment: ........ignorer

Comment: I agree with some of the comments. We need to know the context. Is the person ignoring you because he is angry; autistic; rude; self-absorbed; grieving; or what?

Comment: Shaun, my apologies. Let me clarify a bit. You've ignored a couple suggestions to provide details. But that doesn't mean you deserve you to be labeled; you have that personal freedom. I thought you'd get better answers by adding details. I felt I was free to say that; though unfortunately I didn't do it very well.

Comment: @ShaunWild Do you request noun or adjective?

Comment: Example:

I walk up to someone, ask them a question, they acknowledge this and then look away as if I didn't ask them it.

Or:

I send someone a message, they read it, then ignore it. This makes them a(n) ......... person?

Comment: @Shaun That precise scenario—the one where someone asks you something, you look at them, and then turn away (or even more so if you ask someone a question and then turn away the second they begin to answer it)—is sometimes known here as a _Jewish nan_, for whatever reason. I reckon that's probably quite localised, though, ’cause I've never heard it elsewhere.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If somebody is ignoring others out of superiority complex, then the word is [snobbish](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/snobbish).

If somebody is ignoring others out of one's reserved nature, then the word can be [aloof](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/aloof).

Comment: +1 for a more neutral set of words. Also perhaps *hermit* or *recluse*

Comment: I like the word "Aloof".

Answer (score 9):

The word I would use is *rude*.

Comment: It's not perfect - you can also be rude by very much _not_ ignoring someone; and there are (e.g. embarrassing) situations where someone _wants_ to be ignored and compliance would actually be _polite_...

Answer (score 6):

Consider *[self-absorbed](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/self-absorbed)* (“Overly concerned about oneself, to the point of ignoring the feelings of others”);   *[inconsiderate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inconsiderate#Adjective)* (“Not considerate of others, thoughtless”);  *[egotistical](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/egotistical#Adjective)* (“Believing oneself to be better and more important than others”), and *[arrogant](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/arrogant#Adjective)* (“Having excessive pride in oneself, often with contempt for others”).

Comment: Or simply *absorbed*...if intentionally ignoring people because one is absorbed in his work, for example.

Answer (score 5):

In the spirit of not being more negative when referring to others than I would wish to be used when referring to me I suggest [inattentive](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/inattentive) is the correct word:

> Exhibiting a lack of attention; not attentive

Using neutral terminology encourages you to see communication as a two-way street. Referring to someone with using a negative term implies that it's all their fault and may not encourage you to try to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 5):

**[Neglector](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/neglector)** may apply here       .

Answer (score 5):

[Standoffish](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/standoffish) is a word used to describe a person who is *aloof, distant, haughty*. [Unsociable](http://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr&ei=2vwtUrrBOsbQrQegqoG4Dw#q=unsociable%20meaning) is another word that comes to mind.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use **snubber** or **snob**.

Comment: I am not sure if 'snubber' is a word.

Comment: "Snub" is the correct verb, and a better noun form is "one who snubs."

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps "deaf" is an unexpected answer. I assume you mean someone who does this intentionally or habitually. In that case "opinionated" might apply. They don't want to hear dissenting opinions, so they ignore them.

Comment: _Opinionated_ does not imply ignoring. Often it is the contrary, the opinionated will indeed hear dissenting opinions and disagree. Loudly and at length.

Comment: +1 for _deaf_.  As someone who finds it difficult to hear when there is a lot of background noise, I expect I have been misunderstood as _aloof_ or _snobbish_ or simply _rude_ in the past.  In reality, I just haven't heard what's been said (or I've misunderstood what's been said), so I've either responded with an apparently tangential or unconnected reply, or failed to respond.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the noun *[isolate](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/isolate?q=isolate)*

> a person or thing which has been or become isolated:
>   *social isolates often become careless of their own welfare*

Answer (score 2):

**presumptuous** fits the scenario were one thinks so highly of himself that other people opinions or existence are irrelevant.
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/presumptuous

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the comments above context is everything.

One interpretation of the question is of someone who ignores others in a non-interfering self-centred kind of way - a perfectly rational decision deserving a neutral label. Such a person is an ***egoist***.

> [***egoism***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/egoism?s=t)
>   the habit of valuing everything only in reference to one's personal interest; selfishness

Another interpretation is of a person who is stubborn in a stupid kind of way, mulishly ignoring other people even when they are more sensible or intelligent than them. Such a person is ***pigheaded***, or an **egotist** even.

> [***egotism***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/egotism?s=t)
>   excessive and objectionable reference to oneself in conversation or writing; conceit;

Answer (score 0):

Without context, it's difficult to answer correctly but standoffish works as it's a description that doesn't rely on the person's personality or health status (eg deaf).

Try this experiment on the next stranger you see on the bus who's 'ignoring' others and say to yourself 'that person is snobbish/a snob/reckless/presumptuous' etc which suggests you're aware of their personality. Doesn't work does it?

'That person is standoffish' can be applied to a stranger. The reason for their standoffish behaviour is not relevant, just their current demeanour which you're wanting to describe.

Comment: You could apply that statement to all the suggestions in here Jack.  Without more context from Shaun, it's impossible to provide anything more than a suggestion.